# WxWidgets configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets, msys2

I'm triying to build WxWidgets for using it in C++ using the configure file in Msys2 and I'm getting this problem. I am in Windows 10 and I have gcc and g++ both version 13.2. I have already set the enviroment variables "CC" and "CXX" y tried compiling a basic hello world program in C with gcc and it worked, also I installed both from Msys2 so I think I have all the standar headers. I also got this error triying to use configure files from other projects.

Config.log output variables:

```
## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AIX_CXX_LD=''
AR=''
AROPTIONS=''
BK_DEPS=''
BK_MAKE_PCH=''
BUILT_WX_LIBS=''
CAIRO_CFLAGS=''
CAIRO_LIBS=''
CC='C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe'
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_VISIBILITY=''
COND_BUILD_debug=''
COND_BUILD_debug_DEBUG_INFO_default=''
COND_BUILD_release=''
COND_BUILD_release_DEBUG_INFO_default=''
COND_DEBUG_FLAG_0=''
COND_DEBUG_INFO_0=''
COND_DEBUG_INFO_1=''
COND_DEPS_TRACKING_0=''
COND_DEPS_TRACKING_1=''
COND_GCC_PCH_1=''
COND_ICC_PCH_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_AUI_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_USE_HTML_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_USE_MEDIA_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_USE_QA_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_USE_WEBVIEW_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_PROPGRID_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_RIBBON_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_RICHTEXT_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_STC_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_XML_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_0_USE_XRC_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_AUI_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_GUI_1_USE_HTML_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_GUI_1_USE_MEDIA_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_GUI_1_USE_QA_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_GUI_1_USE_WEBVIEW_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_PROPGRID_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_RIBBON_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_RICHTEXT_1_USE_XML_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_STC_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_XML_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_SHARED_1_USE_XML_1_USE_XRC_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_AUI_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_GUI_1_USE_MEDIA_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_HTML_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_MEDIA_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_PROPGRID_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_QA_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_RIBBON_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_RICHTEXT_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_STC_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_WEBVIEW_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_XML_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_0_USE_XRC_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_1_SHARED_0=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_1_SHARED_1=''
COND_MONOLITHIC_1_USE_STC_1=''
COND_OFFICIAL_BUILD_0_PLATFORM_WIN32_1=''
COND_OFFICIAL_BUILD_1_PLATFORM_WIN32_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_0_USE_SOVERCYGWIN_0_USE_SOVERSION_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_0_USE_SOVERSION_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_PLATFORM_WIN32_1_SHARED_0=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_2_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_3_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_4_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_TOOLKIT_OSX_COCOA_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_TOOLKIT_OSX_COCOA_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_TOOLKIT_OSX_IPHONE_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_TOOLKIT_OSX_IPHONE_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_USE_OPENGL_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_MACOSX_1_USE_SOVERSION_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_OS2_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_UNIX_0=''
COND_PLATFORM_UNIX_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_UNIX_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_2_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_UNIX_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_3_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_UNIX_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_4_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_UNIX_1_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_UNIX_1_USE_PLUGINS_0=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_0=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_0_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_3=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_0_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_4=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_1_SHARED_0=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_2_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_3_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_1_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_4_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_PLATFORM_WIN32_1_TOOLKIT_QT_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_PYTHON=''
COND_SHARED_0=''
COND_SHARED_0_TOOLKIT_MAC_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_SHARED_0_TOOLKIT_MSW_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_USE_OPENGL_1=''
COND_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_wxUSE_LIBJPEG_builtin=''
COND_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_wxUSE_LIBPNG_builtin=''
COND_SHARED_0_USE_GUI_1_wxUSE_LIBTIFF_builtin=''
COND_SHARED_0_USE_STC_1=''
COND_SHARED_0_wxUSE_EXPAT_builtin=''
COND_SHARED_0_wxUSE_REGEX_builtin=''
COND_SHARED_0_wxUSE_ZLIB_builtin=''
COND_SHARED_1=''
COND_SHARED_1_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_SHARED_1_USE_GUI_1_USE_OPENGL_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_=''
COND_TOOLKIT_COCOA=''
COND_TOOLKIT_DFB=''
COND_TOOLKIT_DFB_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_2=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_2_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_2_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_3=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_3_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_3_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_4=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_4_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_4_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION_=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION__USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_TOOLKIT_VERSION__USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_GTK_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_MAC=''
COND_TOOLKIT_MOTIF=''
COND_TOOLKIT_MOTIF_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_MOTIF_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_MSW=''
COND_TOOLKIT_MSW_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_MSW_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_CARBON=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_COCOA=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_COCOA_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_COCOA_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_COCOA_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_IPHONE=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_IPHONE_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_TOOLKIT_OSX_IPHONE_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_QT=''
COND_TOOLKIT_QT_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_TOOLKIT_X11=''
COND_TOOLKIT_X11_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_UNICODE_1=''
COND_USE_CAIRO_1=''
COND_USE_EXCEPTIONS_0=''
COND_USE_EXCEPTIONS_1=''
COND_USE_GUI_0=''
COND_USE_GUI_1=''
COND_USE_GUI_1_USE_OPENGL_1=''
COND_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_0=''
COND_USE_GUI_1_WXUNIV_1=''
COND_USE_GUI_1_wxUSE_LIBJPEG_builtin=''
COND_USE_GUI_1_wxUSE_LIBPNG_builtin=''
COND_USE_GUI_1_wxUSE_LIBTIFF_builtin=''
COND_USE_OPENGL_1=''
COND_USE_PCH_1=''
COND_USE_PLUGINS_0=''
COND_USE_RTTI_0=''
COND_USE_RTTI_1=''
COND_USE_SOTWOSYMLINKS_1=''
COND_USE_SOVERCYGWIN_1_USE_SOVERSION_1=''
COND_USE_SOVERLINUX_1=''
COND_USE_SOVERSION_0=''
COND_USE_SOVERSION_1_USE_SOVERSOLARIS_1=''
COND_USE_SOVERSOLARIS_1=''
COND_USE_STC_1=''
COND_USE_THREADS_0=''
COND_USE_THREADS_1=''
COND_USE_WEBVIEW_WEBKIT2_1=''
COND_USE_XML_1=''
COND_USE_XRC_1=''
COND_WINDOWS_IMPLIB_1=''
COND_WITH_PLUGIN_SDL_1=''
COND_WXUNIV_1=''
COND_wxUSE_EXPAT_builtin=''
COND_wxUSE_LIBJPEG_builtin=''
COND_wxUSE_LIBPNG_builtin=''
COND_wxUSE_LIBTIFF_builtin=''
COND_wxUSE_REGEX_builtin=''
COND_wxUSE_ZLIB_builtin=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe'
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_VISIBILITY=''
DEBUG_FLAG=''
DEBUG_INFO=''
DEFS=''
DEPS_TRACKING=''
DIRECTFB_CFLAGS=''
DIRECTFB_LIBS=''
DISTDIR=''
DLLIMP_SUFFIX=''
DLLPREFIX=''
DLLPREFIX_MODULE=''
DLLTOOL=''
DMALLOC_LIBS=''
DYLIB_RPATH_INSTALL=''
DYLIB_RPATH_POSTLINK=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGL_CFLAGS=''
EGL_LIBS=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTRALIBS=''
EXTRALIBS_GUI=''
EXTRALIBS_HTML=''
EXTRALIBS_MEDIA=''
EXTRALIBS_OPENGL=''
EXTRALIBS_SDL=''
EXTRALIBS_STC=''
EXTRALIBS_WEBVIEW=''
EXTRALIBS_XML=''
GCC=''
GCC_PCH=''
GLU_CFLAGS=''
GLU_LIBS=''
GL_CFLAGS=''
GL_LIBS=''
GNOMEVFS_CFLAGS=''
GNOMEVFS_LIBS=''
GREP=''
GSPELL_CFLAGS=''
GSPELL_LIBS=''
GST_CFLAGS=''
GST_LIBS=''
GTKPRINT_CFLAGS=''
GTKPRINT_LIBS=''
GTK_CFLAGS=''
GTK_CONFIG=''
GTK_LIBS=''
GUIDIST=''
GXX_VERSION=''
HAVE_CXX11=''
HAVE_CXX14=''
HAVE_CXX17=''
HAVE_CXX20=''
HEADER_PAD_OPTION=''
HOST_SUFFIX=''
ICC_PCH=''
ICC_PCH_CREATE_SWITCH=''
ICC_PCH_USE_SWITCH=''
IF_GNU_MAKE=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_DIR=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_GL=''
LDFLAGS_GUI=''
LIBCURL_CFLAGS=''
LIBCURL_LIBS=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBICONV=''
LIBNOTIFY_CFLAGS=''
LIBNOTIFY_LIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPCRE_CFLAGS=''
LIBPCRE_LIBS=''
LIBPREFIX=''
LIBS=''
LIBSECRET_CFLAGS=''
LIBSECRET_LIBS=''
LIBTIFF_CFLAGS=''
LIBTIFF_LIBS=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKE_SET=''
MONOLITHIC=''
MesaGL_CFLAGS=''
MesaGL_LIBS=''
NM=''
OBJCXXFLAGS=''
OBJEXT=''
OFFICIAL_BUILD=''
OPENGL_LIBS=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='wx-dev@googlegroups.com'
PACKAGE_NAME='wxWidgets'
PACKAGE_STRING='wxWidgets 3.2.4'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='wxwidgets'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.2.4'
PANGOFT2_CFLAGS=''
PANGOFT2_LIBS=''
PANGOXFT_CFLAGS=''
PANGOXFT_LIBS=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PIC_FLAG=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_BEOS=''
PLATFORM_MAC=''
PLATFORM_MACOS=''
PLATFORM_MACOSX=''
PLATFORM_UNIX=''
PLATFORM_WIN32=''
PRIVATE_FONTS_CFLAGS=''
PRIVATE_FONTS_LIBS=''
PYTHON=''
QT5_CFLAGS=''
QT5_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
RESCOMP=''
SAMPLES_CXXFLAGS=''
SAMPLES_RPATH_FLAG=''
SAMPLES_SUBDIRS=''
SDL_CFLAGS=''
SDL_CONFIG=''
SDL_LIBS=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHARED=''
SHARED_LD_CC=''
SHARED_LD_CXX=''
SHARED_LD_MODULE_CC=''
SHARED_LD_MODULE_CXX=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SM_CFLAGS=''
SM_LIBS=''
SONAME_FLAG=''
SO_SUFFIX=''
SO_SUFFIX_MODULE=''
STD_BASE_LIBS=''
STD_GUI_LIBS=''
STRIP=''
TOOLCHAIN_FULLNAME=''
TOOLCHAIN_NAME=''
TOOLKIT=''
TOOLKIT_DIR=''
TOOLKIT_LOWERCASE=''
TOOLKIT_VERSION=''
UNICODE=''
USE_DPI_AWARE_MANIFEST=''
USE_GUI=''
USE_MACVERSION=''
USE_PLUGINS=''
USE_SOTWOSYMLINKS=''
USE_SOVERCYGWIN=''
USE_SOVERLINUX=''
USE_SOVERSION=''
USE_SOVERSOLARIS=''
USE_XML=''
VENDOR='custom'
WAYLAND_EGL_CFLAGS=''
WAYLAND_EGL_LIBS=''
WEBKIT_CFLAGS=''
WEBKIT_LIBS=''
WIDGET_SET=''
WINDOWS_IMPLIB=''
WINDRES=''
WITH_PLUGIN_SDL=''
WXCONFIG_CFLAGS=''
WXCONFIG_CPPFLAGS=''
WXCONFIG_CXXFLAGS=''
WXCONFIG_LDFLAGS=''
WXCONFIG_LDFLAGS_GUI=''
WXCONFIG_LIBS=''
WXCONFIG_RESFLAGS=''
WXCONFIG_RPATH=''
WXUNIV=''
WX_CFLAGS=''
WX_CHARTYPE=''
WX_CPPFLAGS=''
WX_CXXFLAGS=''
WX_FLAVOUR=''
WX_LDFLAGS=''
WX_LIBRARY_BASENAME_GUI=''
WX_LIBRARY_BASENAME_NOGUI=''
WX_LIB_FLAVOUR=''
WX_RELEASE='3.2'
WX_SUBVERSION='3.2.4.0'
WX_VERSION='3.2.4'
WX_VERSION_TAG=''
XKBCOMMON_CFLAGS=''
XKBCOMMON_LIBS=''
XMKMF=''
XTST_CFLAGS=''
XTST_LIBS=''
X_CFLAGS=''
X_EXTRA_LIBS=''
X_LIBS=''
X_PRE_LIBS=''
Xinerama_CFLAGS=''
Xinerama_LIBS=''
Xxf86vm_CFLAGS=''
Xxf86vm_LIBS=''
ac_ct_CC='C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-msys'
build_alias='x86_64-pc-msys'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='msys'
build_vendor='pc'
cross_compiling='no'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
dlldir=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-msys'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='msys'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/installation'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
subdirs=''
subdirs_extra=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
wxCFLAGS_C99=''
wxPCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH=''
wxUSE_EXPAT='yes'
wxUSE_LIBJPEG='yes'
wxUSE_LIBPNG='yes'
wxUSE_LIBTIFF='yes'
wxUSE_REGEX='yes'
wxUSE_XML=''
wxUSE_ZLIB='yes'
wx_top_builddir='C:/libs/wxwidgets'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "wxWidgets"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "wxwidgets"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.2.4"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "wxWidgets 3.2.4"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "wx-dev@googlegroups.com"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There'll be a more detailed log somewhere with a failure message

Comment: Any reason why you're not installing prebuilt wxWidgets from MSYS2?

Comment: Why did you remove the part of `config.log` with the actual error? You need to search for the error message you get when running `configure` and you'll see the cause of the problem in the error just above it.

Answer (score 0):

@Camelo,

Please don't use `configure` from the other project.

Please follow following instructions:

1. Remove wxWidgets directory completely.
2. Unpack wxWidgets to some directory (i.e. C:\wxWidgets)
3. Open Msys2 Terminal and do:

3a cd c:\wxWidgets

3b mkdir buildMSW

3c. cd buildMSW

3d. ../configure --with-msw --enable-debug

3e make

3f cd samples\minimal

3g. make

3h. ./minimal

Now Now open the IDE of your choice from MSYS2 Terminal and start writing some code. (If the steps above completed successfully)

BTW, you can compile wxWidgets with MinGW "natively", i.e. from the Windows Command Propmpt.

Do this:

3. On the step 3 open the Command Prompt
4. cd c:\wxWidgets\build\msw
5. Execute: mingw32-bin.exe -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug

Now you can work directly from Windows and forget about MSYS2. Otherwise you will have to work from the MSYS2 terminal.